# Distributed object, large data

Tags: c#, .net, distributed-computing, sharding

I have a general question about large in-memory objects and distributed computing.

I have a large object like Class.Object that stores a lot of data like upwards of 200,000 objects and counting. As it is right now is a simple object created and running in memory and the clients call the data in it. Because speed is also important, I'm serializing this monster into the desk like C# BinaryFormatter and loading and running them. This is a WCF project so the object stays in the memory. My question is how should I scale this across multiple server kind of like distributed computing. Is there a tool in C# like "database sharding" or something like that. Is there a database that I can save this information to. This object isn't just like a simple database table. It has references up and down the classes. Everything is being referenced. There are hashtables etc. Google seems to do this kind of monster indexes using "shards" and splitting the data across different servers. Is there a tool and mechanism to do this in .NET. What is the approach here? I'm using Windows Server AppFabric to save it in memory and load it, but it seems like I need to split this monster object into pieces?

Any pointers and help is appreciated.

Comment: Just because the objects have references to other objects doesn't mean you can't use SQL database, actually, they're quite good at it, using foreign keys. Can you show an example of one of the objects and how are you using them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never listened personally about some already ready to run db sharding solutions in .NET. Would be interesting to read from other posts on this question.

But for general knowledge and may be also pretty useful link can be this one:
[CodeProject destributed computing with Silverlight](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/gridcomputing.aspx?display=Print)

Excelent article, by me.

Good luck.

Comment: The link is about invoking UI objects from other threads, that's doesn't seem to be relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I get no "upvotes" for this answer but the solution to your problem is not some technical sharding but better design. If you need to keep so much objects in memory all the time you need to have some really good incensitive for this. Isn't it possible to load only a portion of this at a time? If a client "call data in it" the client don't have to get all the monster back does he? If no try breaking the thing down to managable parts that a cliente really needs.